# Sort collection (or array of objects) based on id and parent_id attributes

Tags: php, sql, laravel, algorithm, sorting

I came into a problem with sorting Laravel Collection based on object id and object's parent_id attribute.

Currently, I have a Collection of objects in following format:

```
Collection {#563 ▼
  #items: array:20 [▼
    0 => Object {#546 ▶}
    1 => Object {#544 ▶}
    2 => Object {#540 ▶}
    3 => Object {#542 ▶}
    4 => Object {#541 ▶}
    5 => Object {#536 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Each object have following attributes:

```
#attributes: array:8 [▼
        "id" => "70"
        "name" => "Object Name 70"
        "parent_id" => "75"
      ]
```

I need to sort that collection where parent will be first and then children. Then again parent and children. One object will have parent_id NULL. Something more like this:

```
Parent
Child
Child
Parent
Parent
Child
Child
Child
Parent
```

Comment: What you have there is a directed graph, I'm afraid you will have to implement a topological sorting algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

Comment: Would it not be better to `groupBy()` `parent_id`?

Comment: What have you tried? :)

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: Two-level sorting is well documented.  Several useful tree orderings are well documented.  Where are you stuck in providing a viable coding attempt?

Answer (score 0):

Sort the collection by parent_id ( lowest to highest ), then by id ( lowest to highest ) if the parent ids are equal.

This approach assumes that the first element in the collection should be the root parent ( the one with parent_id NULL ) and that in order for an object to be a parent of an object, the parent must exist first and therefore will always have a lower id than any of its children.